# Is there a security risk in adding localhost to Azure AD / app registration redirect URLs?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

For easier local development without having to strip Auth when running in dev mode I would like to add 'localhost:4200' to valid return urls after Azure AD authentication.

Is this bad practice or even a security risk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you would want to use different app registrations (and maybe even different AAD tenants) for production and dev/test.
We use separate tenants for a few reasons:

1. Our development and test environments are not handling production data
2. Developers can be granted higher permissions in the dev/test tenant so they can iterate faster
3. Credentials for dev/test apps don't give potential access to production data

Here the localhost URLs only exist in the dev/test registrations.
I would say having them on production registrations isn't super recommended, as I could make a malicious app that utilizes the localhost redirect on your app to grab a token for the user, and then do whatever actions that user is allowed to do.
This only applies if your app allows usage of e.g. Implicit grant though. 
If your app registration only has URLs for domains you own, this attack would be much harder, if not impossible thanks to browser security controls.

Comment: could you please give a bit of a follow up on what would this attack look like with usage of implicit grant? tnx

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no security risk. For test purpose you can just use `http://localhost:xxx` as the redirect URL in Azure AD app.

And remember to set the same value in your project configuration file.