# Azure App Registration redirect URI modifications vs security implications

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

Microsoft’s [security operations guide for applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/architecture/security-operations-applications#dangling-uri-and-redirect-uri-changes) recommends to alert on changes to `redirect URIs` within Entra App Registrations.

A `redirect URI` or `reply URL` is the location where the authorization server sends the user once the app has been successfully authorized and granted an authorization code or access token. The authorization server then sends the code or token to the `redirect URI`, so Microsoft advises security teams to register the correct location as part of the app registration process.

After studying a bit about `OAuth`, `redirect URIs` I can’t see a feasible way for this to be a critical security concern (if it is, I apologize for my ignorance, asking here to learn).
According to  [OAuth documentation](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/redirect-uri-validation/) there are 3 cases when you’ll need to validate redirect URLs:

- When the developer registers the redirect URL as part of creating an application
- In the authorization request
- When the application exchange an authorization code for an access token
  [image]

[image]

Entra is actually validating the redirect URIs for a given application registered in a Azure tenant based on the `client_id` parameter send  in the request to the authorization server (Entra ID). If anyone would intercept a request to the authorization server and replace the `redirect URI` to a endpoint controlled by a bad actor this wouldn’t work and result in [aadsts50011-reply-url-mismatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50011-reply-url-mismatch) error.

[image]

On a high level I can think of the followin scenarions:

1. Since Entra requires the `redirect URI` to be provided as part of its app registration workflow it can validate the `redirect_uri` parameter against any `redirect URI` values based on the `client_id` value – this should render modifications in the requests by changing the redirect URI to a adversary controlled endpoint before they hit the authz server unsuccessful.
2. Just adding the `redirect URI` in app registration is not enough, one has to make sure that your application is actually aware of the `redirect` URI when forming requests etc. (below code snippet from one of the app registration QuickStart tutorials from the portal) so my understanding is that if someone would add/replace a new `redirect URI`, without actually making the necessary modifications in the app code it wouldn’t honor the new redirect URI – assuming we talk about a legit use of the app

[image]

3. Expanding on 2, assume a user with enough permissions got phished and the threat actor managed to add a new `redirect URI` for an application. Since he has no direct access to the application code, however added a malicious controlled endpoint added as the `redirect URI` he could possibly start phishing users by including a prepared URL for the victim to click that would have the `redirect_uri` value changed to the newly added `redirect_uri`

Also, looking at [this technique](https://securecloud.blog/2021/05/28/using-powershell-to-find-dangling-redirect-uris-in-azure-ad-tenant/) that addresses the issue with so called `dangling redirect URIs`. Assuming the scenario described in the article, the adversary would in my opinion have to be aware of the app registration (needs to know the `client_id`), even if the adversary would be in possession of such information, and would create a new  application that would use the `redirect uri` from the `‘orphaned’` app registration, he/she would still need someone to actually click o a link for the attack to succeed.

Will I agree, this should be monitored, especially any changes outside of change mgmt. workflows it doesn’t appear to me be a quick win technique (I’m of course aware that the fact that there might be no flaws in the Azure implementation as of this moment, this might change, as well with new vulnerabilities in the OAuth protocol).
Are my high level assumptions correct?

Answer (score 0):

It's not about validating whether the redirect_uri is a part of the registered application; it's about keeping track of insecurely applied redirect URIs within the app configuration.

[Security operations for applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/architecture/security-operations-applications#dangling-uri-and-redirect-uri-changes)

> Look for URIs not using HTTPS*, URIs with wildcards at the end or the domain of the URL, URIs that are NOT unique to the application, URIs that point to a domain you don't control.

Changes to critical settings should be audited in case of insecure alterations.

Comment: 1/3 Well, I think it is, because only the fact that a redirect URI has been added, changed doesn’t have to be immediately deemed as a security concern. With my question and argumentation that there’s validation in place I wanted to have a discussion as to what the real threat in changing the redirect URI is, so I think understanding that Entra is performing validation is of importance here. Is adding a redirect URI with http a concern, I guess it is, communication can be intercepted.

Comment: 2/3 Is adding localhost a concern, well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61908514/is-there-a-security-risk-in-adding-localhost-to-azure-ad-app-registration-redi is adding a external domain a concern? To some extent of course it is, but aren’t there cases where you will simply have to use a external domain? What about wildcards as redirect URIs? One still would have to lure a user to use a visit a modified URL that would point to a malicious redirect URI changed in the request to the authorization header.

Comment: 3/3 Or let’s take the action of adding a user to a domain administrator group in AD. We can check if that operation is legitimate, because only few people should be able to do so, is the addition withing change mgmt. procedures, has it been approved etc. with the redirect URI, struggling to understand how one would challenge the addition of the redirect URI pointing to an external domain. I can’t simply tell the dev hey use a different domain.